# Hide Dialog box when running append query in VBA ODBC

Tags: ms-access, vba, odbc

I want to run a saved access query through a button click using VBA. I don't want the user to be asked to confirm that it runs.

CODE:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "QryAddTraining", acViewNormal, acAdd
```

This brings up the dialogue box "You are about to run append query that will modify data in your table" ....

I just want the VBA code to automatically select "Yes" and stop the user from seeing this interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DAO.Database.Execute` to execute your query:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "QryAddTraining", dbFailOnError
```

The `dbFailOnError` option is not required, but including it gives you better error information.  Check the Access help topic for details.

Comment: You can also use `DoCmd.Setwarnings False`, but I prefer the method suggested by @HansUp, as it allows you to identify other types of errors not shown when `SetWarnings` is turned off. (If you use `SetWarnings`, don't forget to turn it back on when you are done.)

Comment: A quick tip for writing shorter code: You can replace 3 lines with


`CurrentDB.Execute "QryAddTraining", dbFailOnError`